# How to inherit system defined style in my style file in android?

Tags: android

I customize a style named MyDialogWindowTitle in my style file, I hope this style inherited from system style Widget.TextView.ListSeparator, 
butthe code  `parent="@style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator"` cause an error, how can I do ? Thanks!

```
<style name="MyDialogWindowTitle" parent="?android: style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator">       
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>            
</style>



<style name="Widget.TextView.ListSeparator">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/dark_header_dither</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">25dip</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `parent="?android: style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator"`, use `parent="@style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator"`

This is because `Widget.TextView.ListSeparator` is defined by you and is not defined in android's libraries

Comment: Thanks! But Widget.TextView.ListSeparator is defined in android's libraries. I hope to  inherit from system style Widget, so I write the code <style name="MyDialogWindowTitle" parent="?android: style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator">, but I get an error

Comment: The error info is : error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator'. styles.xml /CallerNameTalker/res/values line 15 Android AAPT Problem